# Where is the amazon instance private key file?

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2

I dont even know if that question makes sense. But I am completely 100% new at this and I need some assistance. I am trying to create an instance on amazon so I can connect to it and add files with ssh and so on.

Now Ive followed the guidelines and I have created my instance. However, when I am reading the directions on how to remote into it, it refers to a private key file that apparently has password information or something (with a .pem it says). Ive scanned the tutorials, google, I feel like ive clicked every tab and link on the amazon console and I can still not find this file. All the documentation says is "I created the file when I launched the instance."

So purely on an amazon standpoint, where is this file? It is on amazon? ssh? some registry? I have no clue. This is a bottom shelf question so I apologize if its not clear. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should have the file on your local computer. while creating a new instance, one of the steps of the wizard, is to create a keypair, and download the corresponding .pem file. maybe you didnt click the download key link? seeing this is your first attempt, i would guess you havent done any work with your instance yet, so terminate it, and start again.

hope this helps

Comment: thanks a ton man. I have no idea how I missed that.

Comment: One more thing, if you somehow lost the key, you can't download it again. So create another one from the Console and download the new one.